# Google Cloud Functions (with Firebase) causing Res.on TypeError

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to use a Google Cloud Function to send a notification to a user based on an HTTP call from my Firebase flutter app, but I'm running into this error: `TypeError: res.on is not a function` every time I try to test it. Any ideas what could be causing it?

## Function Code

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sendPing = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  const { taskOrHabit, senderName, taskOrHabitName, recipientUid } = data;

  // Fetch necessary information from Firestore
  const recipientSnapshot = await admin.firestore().collection('users').doc(recipientUid).get();
 
  const recipientToken = recipientSnapshot.data().fcmToken; // Replace 'fcmToken' with your FCM token field.

  // Construct the notification message
  const message = {
    notification: {
      title: `${senderName} pinged you`,
      body: `${senderName} is reminding you to complete your ${taskOrHabit}: ${taskOrHabitName}`,
    },
    token: recipientToken,
  };

  // Send the notification
  await admin.messaging().send(message);

  return { success: true };
});
```

## Error Message

```
TypeError: res.on is not a function
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:392:17
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at /workspace/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/common/providers/https.js:391:16
    at httpHandler (/workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:132:16)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/function_wrappers.js:99:29
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11)
```

Also, my package.json code has the following:

```
{
    "dependencies": {
      "@google-cloud/functions-framework": "^3.0.0",
      "firebase-admin": "^11.10.1",
      "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you ever had success with any other cloud functions in this project? If not then there may have been an installation error. Because this error isn't coming from your source code. What I would do is reinstall Firebase Cloud Functions into a new folder and try again. If that doesn't remedy it, I would go back as far as you can to step 1, which in your case may have been installing Node.JS or npm onto your computer, and starting over from there. Because this hints of an installation error.

Comment: I have same error. Did u find the solution?

Comment: How are you installing your Cloud Functions J.Dragon? I was initially doing it via cloud console, but completely restarted and started doing it from local code in VS Code, and deploying via the Firebase command line tools.

Comment: So I'm not sure what exactly fixed it, but doing it that way made the difference for me.

Comment: I seem to have been able to fix it by completely deleting the function from Firebase and re-creating it